# Digital Ocean App build fail saying can't authenticate npm

Tags: node.js, npm, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

I'm trying to install Strapi V4 on a Digital Ocean App; I think I have everything set up properly between GitHub and Digital Ocean, but when I try to run a build, I get the following errors:

```
[2022-06-24 00:13:32] => Initializing build
[2022-06-24 00:13:32] => Retrieving source code to /workspace
[2022-06-24 00:13:32] => Selecting branch "main"
[2022-06-24 00:13:33] => Checking out commit "a10bd1fc98f396ddf9255ccb7dc8e9d5eae6a201"
[2022-06-24 00:13:33] => Got source_dir: /
[2022-06-24 00:13:33] => Using workspace root /workspace
[2022-06-24 00:13:33] 
[2022-06-24 00:13:33] => Building app using buildpacks
[2022-06-24 00:13:33] => Injecting app environment variables:
[2022-06-24 00:13:33]      NODE_ENV URL APP_KEYS API_TOKEN_SALT ADMIN_JWT_SECRET JWT_SECRET
[2022-06-24 00:13:33] => Configuring custom build command to be run at the end of the build:
[2022-06-24 00:13:33]      npm run build
[2022-06-24 00:13:34] => Running buildpack detection
[2022-06-24 00:13:34] 
[2022-06-24 00:13:34] heroku/nodejs-engine  0.5.1
[2022-06-24 00:13:34] digitalocean/node     0.3.4
[2022-06-24 00:13:34] digitalocean/procfile 0.0.3
[2022-06-24 00:13:34] digitalocean/custom   0.1.0
[2022-06-24 00:13:34] 
[2022-06-24 00:13:34] For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
[2022-06-24 00:13:34]    Node.js: https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
[2022-06-24 00:13:35] 
[2022-06-24 00:13:35] => Building app
[2022-06-24 00:13:35] 
[2022-06-24 00:13:35] ---> Node.js Buildpack
[2022-06-24 00:13:35] ---> Installing toolbox
[2022-06-24 00:13:35] ---> - jq
[2022-06-24 00:13:35] ---> - yj
[2022-06-24 00:13:35] ---> Getting Node version
[2022-06-24 00:13:35] ---> Resolving Node version
[2022-06-24 00:13:37] ---> Downloading and extracting Node v16.15.1
[2022-06-24 00:13:52] ---> Parsing package.json
[2022-06-24 00:13:53] ---> No file to start server
[2022-06-24 00:13:53] ---> either use 'docker run' to start container or add index.js or server.js
[2022-06-24 00:13:53] Project contains package-lock.json, using npm
[2022-06-24 00:13:53] Using npm v8.11.0 matching the requested version range ">=6.0.0" in package.json->engines.npm
[2022-06-24 00:13:53] Installing node_modules using npm (from package-lock.json)
[2022-06-24 00:13:54] Running npm ci
[2022-06-24 00:13:54] 
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN While resolving: @strapi/design-system@1.1.1
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN Found: @strapi/icons@1.1.1
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN node_modules/@strapi/admin/node_modules/@strapi/icons
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN   @strapi/icons@"1.1.1" from @strapi/admin@4.1.12
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN   node_modules/@strapi/admin
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN     @strapi/admin@"4.1.12" from @strapi/strapi@4.1.12
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN     node_modules/@strapi/strapi
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN 
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN peer @strapi/icons@"^0.0.1-alpha.73" from @strapi/design-system@1.1.1
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN node_modules/@strapi/admin/node_modules/@strapi/design-system
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN   @strapi/design-system@"1.1.1" from @strapi/admin@4.1.12
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN   node_modules/@strapi/admin
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN 
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @strapi/icons@0.0.1-alpha.79
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN node_modules/@strapi/icons
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN   peer @strapi/icons@"^0.0.1-alpha.73" from @strapi/design-system@1.1.1
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN   node_modules/@strapi/admin/node_modules/@strapi/design-system
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN     @strapi/design-system@"1.1.1" from @strapi/admin@4.1.12
[2022-06-24 00:13:57] npm WARN     node_modules/@strapi/admin
[2022-06-24 00:14:09] npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[2022-06-24 00:14:10] npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
[2022-06-24 00:14:10] npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
[2022-06-24 00:14:10] npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
[2022-06-24 00:14:12] npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
[2022-06-24 00:14:12] npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
[2022-06-24 00:14:14] npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[2022-06-24 00:14:15] npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@3.12.0: This project is unmaintained
[2022-06-24 00:14:17] npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
[2022-06-24 00:14:18] npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: 
[2022-06-24 00:14:21] npm WARN deprecated buildmail@3.10.0: This project is unmaintained
[2022-06-24 00:14:28] npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.12.1:  This package has been deprecated in favor of separate inclusion of a polyfill and regenerator-runtime (when needed). See the @babel/polyfill docs (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) for more information.
[2022-06-24 00:14:29] npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
[2022-06-24 00:14:33] npm WARN deprecated sequelize@5.22.5: Please update to v6 or higher! A migration guide can be found here: https://sequelize.org/v6/manual/upgrade-to-v6.html
[2022-06-24 00:14:41] npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm notice 
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.11.0 -> 8.13.1
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.13.1>
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.13.1` to update!
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm notice 
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR! code E401
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR! 
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR!     npm login
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] 
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] npm ERR!     /home/apps/.npm/_logs/2022-06-24T00_13_54_861Z-debug-0.log
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] 
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] unable to invoke layer creator
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] installing node_modules: exit status 1
[2022-06-24 00:15:10] ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[2022-06-24 00:15:11] 
[2022-06-24 00:15:11] For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
[2022-06-24 00:15:11]    Node.js: https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
[2022-06-24 00:15:11] 
[2022-06-24 00:15:11]  ! Build failed (145)
[]
```

The part about it not authenticating has me confused. With a DO App, I can't find a way to edit any configurations really for npm authentication so I'm at a loss.